# Counting the number of occurrences of a word in a file without using grep and wc?

Tags: perl

How i would count the appearance of a word in a text file without using `grep` and `wc`? I know how to do it with using grep and wc, but not without. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look up 'perl associative arrays'.

Comment: Looked them up, didn't seem of much help. Any other ideas?

Comment: why? homework question? Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: [perlfaq4 - How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string%3f)

Comment: Hashes haven't been called "associative arrays" for twenty years (since Perl 5 was released). If you search information on "associative arrays" then you're going to end up with some seriously outdated information!

Comment: Not a homework question, something just using for enhancing my own knowlege

Answer (score 0):

You can try with perl one-liner as below:

**Windows Command Prompt:**

```
perl -lne "if($_ =~ /word-pattern/) { $a++;} ; END { print \"No of words in the file:\"; print $a}" Inpufile
```

**Unix Shell prompt:**

```
perl -lne 'if($_ =~ /word-pattern/) { $a++;} ; END { print "No of words in the file:"; print $a}' Inputfile
```